# How can I display data of the ListBox item in the dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF program I have **ListBox** control:

```
<ListBox x:Name="mailsListBox" SelectionChanged="mailsListBox_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBoxItem Content="..." Background="#FFF3F3F3" Margin="0,0,0,1" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="..." Margin="0,0,0,1"/>
    <!-- ... -->
    <ListBoxItem Content="..." Background="#FFF3F3F3" Margin="0,0,0,1" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="..." Margin="0,0,0,1"/>
</ListBox>
```

When I press on it's component, I need to show a [dialog](http://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html) window, but here what I have:

[image]

Displays the corresponding value:

```
public class Emails
{
    public Emails()
    {
        AddMailsToList();
    }

    public List<string> mailsList = new List<string>();

    public void AddMailsToList()
    {
        MainWindow obj = new MainWindow();
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[0].ToString());
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[1].ToString());
        //...
        mailsList.Add(obj.mailsListBox.Items[9].ToString());

        // title of the mail
        mailsList.Add("You have new message");
    }
}
```

Interception click event to an element ListBox:

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    private async void mailsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Emails obj = new Emails();

        await this.ShowMessageAsync(
            obj.mailsList[10],
            obj.mailsList[mailsListBox.SelectedIndex]);
    }
}
```

How can I display only data which I need in the dialog?

**Edit1:**

I thins I have a wrong code structure and I need to use `ItemsSource`, but I don't know how to..

Comment: In your 'AddMailsToList', why do you do "MainWindow obj = new MainWindow();" ? because you create a new window, obj.mailsListBox should be empty, isn't it ?

Comment: @carndacier Because it is not in the class of the form, which contain `ListBox`. That's why I need `obj` to access `ListBoxItems` from another class

Comment: Can you give me more details about what you want ?
You want, when you click on an item in your listbox, display a dialog displaying the selected item text ?

Comment: @carndacier Yes, exactly. I neet to display only text without  `System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the point of the `Email` class, and I think you definitely have a data model structure problem.

But if you just want to display the text of the selected item of your listbox, give a try to that :

```
    private void mailsListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;
        if (lb != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lb.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        {
            await this.ShowMessageAsync(
        ((ListBoxItem)lb.SelectedItem).Content.ToString(),
        obj.mailsList[mailsListBox.SelectedIndex]);
        }
    }
```

Always check if user has selected an item. if you use mailsListBox.SelectedIndex and user hasn't select anything, it will return -1, and it will throw an error when you try to access to item at position "-1" of an array :)

Comment: `ShowMessageAsync` is a function from MahApps.Metro library like `MessageBox.Show()`. It create a dialog window like on the screenshot. First argument is a title and second - content. Now I still have text `System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem` :(

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used this function before.
I've edited my answer, give it a try

Comment: No problem ;) but by curiosity, what is email used for ?

Comment: I just tried to combine all mails in one `List`, but now I understood that I don't need it, already deleted that code)